# OAuth com Injeção de dependencias

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, ddd, oauth2, injeção-de-dependência

Olá, estou iniciando os estudos com OAuth, e logo de cara me deparei com um problema. Criei a famosa classe 'Startup', e nela eu chamo meu provider da seguinte maneira:

```js
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }

    static Startup()
    {
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/autenticar"),
            /*chamada do provider*/
            Provider = new OAuthProvider()
        };
    }

}
```

Porém o construtor dessa classe aplica uma injeção de dependências no construtor da seguinte forma:

```js
 IUsuariosServices _usuariosServices;

public OAuthProvider(IUsuariosServices usuariosServices)
{
    _usuariosServices = usuariosServices;
}
```

Para assim poder realizar as funções inseridas nessa interface.

Ficando assim:

```js
 public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        string email = context.UserName;
        string senha = context.Password;
        /* Chamada da função da injeção de dependências */
        var usuario = _usuariosServices.Login(email, senha);
    });
}
```

Porém na minha classe 'Startup', na chamada da classe provider acontece um erro pedindo um parâmetro da classe!

***mensagem de erro***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema é? Que parâmetro é esse? Como passar como parâmetro uma injeção de dependências? É isso mesmo que tem que fazer?

Agradeço desde já...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ele está esperando uma instância de `IUsuariosServices`, você definiu isso aqui

```
IUsuariosServices _usuariosServices;

public OAuthProvider(IUsuariosServices usuariosServices)//Aqui diz que que o construtor base dela precisa de uma instância de IUsuariosServices 
{
    _usuariosServices = usuariosServices;
}
```

Como resolver:

Passando uma instância de `IUsuariosServices` para ele

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
    }

    static Startup()
    {
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/autenticar"),
            /*chamada do provider*/
            Provider = new OAuthProvider(new UsuariosServices())//Estou supondo que a implementação de IUsuariosServices é UsuariosServices
        };
    }    
}
```

Possível problema, dependendo da arquitetura que você está utilizando seu `UsuarioService` deve esperar um outro objeto instanciado nele, a resolução é a mesma, passar a instância. Não sei a arquitetura que está utilizando, mas pode ser que fique algo assim:

```
Provider = new OAuthProvider(new UsuariosServices(new UsuarioRepository(New SeuDbContext)()))
```

Uma das ideias de usar injeção de dependência é fugir disso.

**Exemplo consumindo com e sem injeção de dependência:**

```
//Aqui é criada uma interface de repositorio
public interface ITesteRepository
{
    void Insert(Teste teste);
}

//Aqui é criada uma classe que irá implementar a interface ITesteRepository
public class TesteRepository : ITesteRepository
{
    public void Insert(Teste teste)
    {
        Context.Insert(teste)    
    }
}

//Aqui está sendo criado outra interface
public interface ITesteService
{
    void Insert(Teste teste);
}

//Aqui é criada uma classe que implementa a ITesteService
public class TesteService : ITesteService
{
    //Aqui estou criando via injeção de dependencia uma instancia do repositorio, pois vou usar ela em baixo
    private ITesteRepository _repositorioPorInjecao;
    public TesteService(ITesteRepository repositorioPorInjecao)
    {
        _repositorioPorInjecao = repositorioPorInjecao;
    }

    public void Insert(Teste teste)
    {
        _repositorioPorInjecao.Insert(teste);
    }
}

public class TestesController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Insert(Teste teste)
    {
        //Aqui estou criando SEM injeção de dependencia uma inetancia da service, note que o construtor base dela espera uma instancia de ITesteRepository por isso dei new em uma classe que implementa tal interface
        ITesteService serviceSemInjecao = new TesteService(new TesteRepository());
        serviceSemInjecao.Insert(Teste);
        return Json(new { Mensagem = "Sucesso!!" });
    }
}
```

Comment: Na verdade isso não tem muito sentido, pois apenas passo uma interface e não tem como inciar uma interface. É injeção de dependência, aonde informo qual classe aquela interface representa e a instância da mesma é criado no construtor da classe que irá utiliza-la

Comment: Você não vai passar uma interface, acontece que precisa de uma instância que implementa aquela interface.  Na classe startup não tem um construtor, se não você poderia injetar dependência lá também

Comment: Poderia mostrar um exemplo?

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes Adicionei 1 exemplo, não sei se ficou didático, mais a noite tentarei melhorar.

Comment: Aeh, rapaz, funcionou direitinho, muito obrigado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNunes Maravilha, se ficou alguma duvida fico feliz em tentar responder ;)